# Mongoose Model, cleaning/parsing an Array efficiently

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having some issues with a mongoose array, it's likely due to my lacking understanding of the library, and I can't find the exact answer I'm looking for in the docs.

For starters I have my schema and model declarations:

```
const gConfig = new Schema({ aList:  Array, maxChanLimit: Number }), globalConfiguration = mongoose.model('globalConfig', gConfig);
```

And I have my command which fetches the array, parses out _id, then pushes the new item to the array, and overwrites the existing one in the database.

```
    if((message.author.id === g.ownerID) && (g.id.toString() === tocGuild) && message.content.startsWith("!updatealist")) 
{ 
    let mc = message.content.replace("!updatealist ", "");
    globalConfiguration.findOneAndUpdate({},{$push: {"aList":mc }}, { upsert: true }, function(err, data) { 
        if (err) return console.log(err); 
            var str = JSON.stringify(data); str = str.replace(RegExp(/"_id"|"__v"|'/g),""); var arr = str.split(`","`);
        });
}
```

I feel like there has to be a better way to do this, I've tried something like this based on what I've read:

```
globalConfiguration.findOneAndUpdate({},{$push: {"-_id aList":mc }}
```

However this did not remove _id from the array. I suppose how I'm doing it is a way to do it, but I know it isn't efficient, and isn't dynamic at all, it's also extremely bulky in terms of code and could be streamlined using the library.

In practice, what is the best way to properly read an array from a model with Mongoose? How do you read from the array without the additional objects Mongoose adds by default? What is the best way to add an item to an existing model?

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to have more control over the updating process, you can do it like this, in the mongoose documents it suggest you can first query the item/document you want to update, once that document is queried and there, you can make changes to it such as if it contains an array , you can push to it or pop from it or what ever..

its in your control

so,

```
   if((message.author.id === g.ownerID) && (g.id.toString() === tocGuild) && message.content.startsWith("!updatealist")) 
{ 
    let mc = message.content.replace("!updatealist ", "");
    globalConfiguration.findOne({"your query"}, function(err, data) { 
        if (err) throw (err); 
            data.array.push("something");

            data.save();// save it again with updates
            var str = JSON.stringify(data); str = str.replace(RegExp(/"_id"|"__v"|'/g),""); var arr = str.split(`","`);
        });
}
```